# Python "decimal" package gives wrong results

Tags: python, decimal, precision

I tried to compute the following by setting `getcontext().prec = 800`.

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 800
>>> Decimal(22.0) / Decimal ( 10.0) - Decimal ( 0.2 )
Decimal('1.999999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875')
>>>
```

But the expected result is `2`. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can read more on the limitations here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Uh, you asked for 800 digits of precision, you got lots of digits of precision... the code is working exactly as written

Comment: but its not correct computation.

Comment: Because **the floating-point representation of 22.0 and 10.0 isn't exact** (nor of 0.2). There are 2700 SO posts documenting that. If you really need to do fixed-point arithmetic (which is basically integer arithmetic with a scaling factor), then do fixed-point arithmetic.

Comment: @smci The floating-point representations of 22.0 and 10.0 are exact, of course - all integers smaller in absolute value than 2^53 should have exact representations as double-precision floating point numbers. It's 0.2 that's the problem.

Comment: @kaya3: yes thanks for the correction. It's 0.2 that is inexact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you construct a Decimal from a floating-point number, you get the exact value of the floating-point number, which may not precisely match the decimal value because that's how floating-point numbers work.

If you want to do precise decimal arithmetic, construct your Decimal objects from strings instead of floating-point numbers:

```
>>> Decimal('22.0') / Decimal('10.0') - Decimal('0.2')
Decimal('2.0')
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass strings to the Decimal constructor instead of floats: `Decimal('0.2')` gives the result you expect, `Decimal(0.2)`  doesn't.

This is because:

> If value is a float, the binary floating point value is losslessly converted to its exact decimal equivalent. This conversion can often require 53 or more digits of precision. For example, Decimal(float('1.1')) converts to Decimal('1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625').

https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to give numbers as a string to prevent them from being evaluated as floating point.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 800
print(Decimal(0.2))
print(Decimal('0.2'))
print(Decimal('22.0') / Decimal ('10.0') - Decimal ('0.2' ))
```

which gives

```
0.200000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125
0.2
2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `prec` attribute defines how many numbers after the decimal point will round your number. For example, if you expect `2.00`, its value should be `3`. Or if you want to round the number so that it has no decimal places you can use `1` as a parameter.

```
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 1
print(Decimal(22.0) / Decimal ( 10.0) - Decimal ( 0.2 ))
>> 2
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if i am unable to predict the precision of result, then in that case i will set a higher precision and expect a correct answer.