# How to fix error with decimal numbers in Python?

Tags: python, decimal

I have program which generates table which I need.
When difference between numbers was enough large(about 5 points), everything was ok.
So I decided to use Decimal library. But when I added that module to the program, everything was broken(numbers were the same).
Here is my output(few start lines) with Decimal

```
0.00402787895809813677877597726251   0.00402787895809813677877597726251
0.00402787895809813677877597726251   0.00402787895809813677877597726251
0.00402787895809813677877597726251   0.00402787895809813677877597726251
```

As you can see they are the same, however base numbers are different.
How to fix that bug?

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 30
ls = [1,4,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]
#N = Decimal(22)
l = Decimal(0.0040278789580981364238)
r = Decimal(0.0040278789580981370940)
one = Decimal(r-l)/Decimal(22)
print(len(ls))
for elem in ls:
    print(Decimal(l),'\t',Decimal(l)+Decimal(one)*Decimal(elem))
    l+=Decimal(one)*Decimal(elem)
```

Comment: Can you explain what your output is supposed to be versus what you're getting?

Comment: Creating decimals from floats is only going to be as accurate as the floats in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python "decimal" package gives wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927128/python-decimal-package-gives-wrong-results)

Answer (score 4):

You need to construct Decimals from strings, not floats:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(0.0040278789580981370940)
Decimal('0.004027878958098136778775977262512242305092513561248779296875')
>>> Decimal(0.0040278789580981364238)
Decimal('0.004027878958098136778775977262512242305092513561248779296875')
>>> Decimal("0.0040278789580981370940")
Decimal('0.0040278789580981370940')
>>> Decimal("0.0040278789580981364238")
Decimal('0.0040278789580981364238')
```

Floats have limited precision, which means that both `0.0040278789580981370940` and `0.0040278789580981364238` are "rounded" to the same number internally (more details on why this is unavoidable, see [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)).

```
>>> 0.0040278789580981364238
0.004027878958098137
>>> 0.0040278789580981370940
0.004027878958098137
```

If you use a string as the contructor, a Decimal can be built with arbitrary precision.

Comment: This is the right approach. @Tim I think the answer would be much improved if you explained why using strings, rather than floats, is the way to maintain precision. That seems to me the underlying confusion here.

Comment: Yeah, I'm super confused. Why on Earth would it behave like this?