# Python: Float to Decimal conversion and subsequent shifting may give wrong result

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion, decimal

When I convert a `float` to `decimal.Decimal` in Python and afterwards call `Decimal.shift` it may give me completely wrong and unexpected results depending on the float. Why is this the case?

Converting 123.5 and shifting it:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal(123.5)
print(a.shift(1))  # Gives expected result
```

The code above prints the expected result of `1235.0`.

If I instead convert and shift 123.4:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

a = Decimal(123.4)
print(a.shift(1))  # Gives UNexpected result
```

it gives me `3.418860808014869689941406250E-18` (approx. 0) which is completely unexpected and wrong.

Why is this the case?

---

Note:
I understand the floating-point imprecision because of the representation of floats in memory. However, I can't explain why this should give me such a completely wrong result.

Edit:
Yes, in general it would be best to not convert the floats to decimals but convert strings to decimals instead. However, this is not the point of my question. I want to understand why the shifting after float conversion gives such a completely wrong result. So if I `print(Decimal(123.4))` it gives `123.40000000000000568434188608080148696899414062` so after shifting I would expect it to be `1234.0000000000000568434188608080148696899414062` and not nearly zero.

Comment: The `shift` and `rotate` methods are based on the current precision (defaulting to `28`); a coefficient that's longer than 28 digits will have its most significant digits truncated _before_ the `shift` and `rotate` operations. This is the way that the reference implementation ("decNumber") for Mike Cowlishaw's standard behaves. See https://bugs.python.org/issue7233 for more.

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting something like this. If you post this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @MarkDickinson This is great extra info, I did not see your comment until after updating my answer, but will include this as well.

Comment: @DanSafee: Thanks, much appreciated. (I probably won't have time to write my own answer ...)

Comment: [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927128/python-decimal-package-gives-wrong-results) on the issue with using `float` instead of `str` to initiate a `Decimal` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the Decimal constructor input to use strings instead of floats.

```py
a = Decimal('123.5')
print(a.shift(1))

a = Decimal('123.4')
print(a.shift(1))
```

or

```py
a = Decimal(str(123.5))
print(a.shift(1))

a = Decimal(str(123.4))
print(a.shift(1))
```

The output will be as expected.

```sh
>>> 1235.0
>>> 1234.0
```

Decimal instances can be constructed from integers, strings, floats, or tuples. Construction from an integer or a float performs an exact conversion of the value of that integer or float.

For floats, Decimal calls `Decimal.from_float()`

> Note that Decimal.from_float(0.1) is not the same as Decimal('0.1'). Since 0.1 is not exactly representable in binary floating point, the value is stored as the nearest representable value which is 0x1.999999999999ap-4.  The exact equivalent of the value in decimal is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625.

Internally, the Python decimal library converts a float into two integers representing the numerator and denominator of a fraction that yields the float.

```py
n, d = abs(123.4).as_integer_ratio()
```

It then calculates the bit length of the denominator, which is the number of bits required to represent the number in binary.

```py
k = d.bit_length() - 1
```

And then from there the bit length `k` is used to record the coefficient of the decimal number by multiplying the numerator * 5 to the power of the bit length of the denominator.

```py
coeff = str(n*5**k)
```

The resulting values are used to create a new Decimal object with constructor arguments of `sign`, `coefficient`, and `exponent` using this values.

For the float `123.5` these values are

```sh
>>> 1 1235 -1
```

and for the float `123.4` these values are

```sh
1 123400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625 -45
```

So far, nothing is amiss.

However when you call shift, the Decimal library has to calculate how much to pad the number with zeroes based on the shift you've specified. To do this internally it takes the precision subtracted by length of the coefficient.

```py
amount_to_pad = context.prec - len(coeff)
```

The default precision is only 28 and with a float like `123.4` the coefficient becomes much longer than the default precision as noted above. This creates a negative amount to pad with zeroes and makes the number very tiny as you noted.

A way around this is to increase the precision to the length of the exponent + the length of the number you started with (45 + 4).

```py
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 49

a = Decimal(123.4)
print(a)
print(a.shift(1))
```

```sh
>>> 123.400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625
>>> 1234.000000000000056843418860808014869689941406250
```

The documentation for `shift` hints that the precision is important for this calculation:

> The second operand must be an integer in the range -precision through precision.

However it does not explain this caveat for floats that don't play nice with memory limitations.

I would expect this to raise some kind of error and prompt you to change your input or increase the precision, but at least you know!

@MarkDickinson noted in a comment above that you can view this Python bug tracker for more information: https://bugs.python.org/issue7233

Comment: Yes that is true but that should not give such an utterly wrong result or should it? I want to understand why this gives such a completely wrong result.

So if I `print(Decimal(123.4))`  it gives `123.40000000000000568434188608080148696899414062` so after shifting I would expect it to be `1234.0000000000000568434188608080148696899414062` and not nearly zero.

Comment: It's related to the default precision being 28 and the resulting coefficient of that float being much longer than the precision. Increase the precision and the problem goes away. I updated the answer.